# Number of dinners

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

How many dinners consist of 2 optional appetisers, 3 main courses and 4 optional beverages?

My result is $2\cdot 3\cdot4 + 2\cdot3 + 3\cdot4 + 3 = 45$. Where the first product $2\cdot3\cdot4$ represent having 2 appetiser choices, 3 main dish choices and 4 beverage choices. Then the pluses represent OR. So we have further: OR having 2 appetiser choices and 3 main course choices OR 3 main courses and 4 beverages OR just 3 main courses.

But why is the above reasoning wrong? (The correct answer is $3\cdot3\cdot4$.)

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. Another way of seeing it is that there are $3$ choices for appetisers $3$ for mains and $5$ for beverages (allowing for the option of not choosing either an appetiser or a beverage), giving us $3 \times 3 \times 5 = 45$ dinners. Where did the "correct" answer come from?

Comment: Interesting point about the option of not choosing, I've seen our professor use that technique. The "correct" answer comes from R Johnsonbaugh, Discrete Mathematics, 8th Edition, Solution manual, section 6.1, problem 2. I'll try to see if this is a known typo.

Comment: Do you have the exact wording of the problem? It sounds like he is saying you can choose zero appetizers but you must choose one beverage. We could also get three as the number of appetizers by choosing either appetizer or both. Is it really worded the way you have it on the first line of your post?

Comment: Your reasoning is sound. The correct answer is 45. It must be a mistake from your source.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.
Other way to think is: when a type of item is optional, you can include an extra option which is "not choosing". Than the problems turns simple:

$N=3\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \\
N=45$

When we came across with an answer error, it's difficult sometimes to consider that the author may committed a mistake. But, in fact, that's the case, your solution is the correct one :)